# Issues restoring iPhone 11 Pro from an iTunes backup

Tags: itunes, backup, restore

I've been trying to restore the latest backup (made last night) onto my iPhone 11 Pro, and I've been running into quite a few issues.

The full backup (the encrypted type) is on my PC's iTunes.

The first strange occurrence was when I plugged the phone into the PC, it started acting like it was backing up automatically, thus disabling the "Restore backup" option (although automatic backups are disabled, as are wifi and iCloud backups). I stopped the process several times to keep my "good" backup from being replaced, but when I eventually let it go through, the time of the current backup was unchanged (so still the "good" backup apparently).

Once the fake backing up process finished, I tried clicking on the "Restore Backup" radio button, but a message appeared telling me there was not enough space left on my iPhone to restore the Backup (there were 6GB free left). I tried deleting videos to clear up some space, to no avail (there was around 210GB used out of the 256 once I did some deleting).

The phone would then prompt me to sign in again (although I hadn't shut it down)

Then, I tried going the "Restore iPhone" route, to clear the phone's memory to make room for a backup restore. I disabled Find My, but then I got messages telling me I needed to update the software first, and then update iTunes: but then it found that iTunes was up to date, so that went nowhere.

Since Restore iPhone seemed to be going nowhere, and the supposed issue was space, I went ahead and pressed "erase all content and settings" directly on the phone.

That completed, I went back to "Restore Backup" on iTunes, which at first started running and calculating the time left, but around the "32 minutes left" mark, a pop-up appeared saying:

"iTunes could not restore the iPhone "xxx" because an error occurred while reading from or writing to the iPhone".

When I tried again, it started to update music tracks on my phone - which it normally does at the END of the restore backup process. I noticed that iTunes showed the phone's memory had 30GB worth of audio, although the phone had supposedly been wiped.

I am still stuck with the above "iTunes could not restore the iPhone" message above each time I try to restore the backup.

My goal is obviously to get all the data and settings back onto my phone, and not to damage or delete the backup while doing so.
I realize there's a lot of different issues that seem to come into play here, but hopefully it will all make sense to someone more experienced than myself.

I put the phone in DFU mode while connected to iTunes, and it started to restore the backup again, with no odd actions this time. It went to the point in the countdown where there were 2 hours left (so longer than last time), but then I got the error message again ("iTunes could not restore the iPhone "xxx" because an error occurred while reading from or writing to the iPhone"), and then "iTunes could not connect to this iPhone. An unknown error occurred (0xE800000A)."

Are there restore options I’m missing?

Comment: See if you can get any further by putting the phone into DFU mode, then connecting to iTunes - there's a method here - https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/force-restart-iphone-11-iphone-11-pro-max/

Comment: Thanks for the tip and link. I put the phone in DFU mode while connected to iTunes, and it started to restore the backup again, with no odd actions this time. It went to the point in the countdown where there were 2 hours left (so longer than last time), but then I got the error message again ("iTunes could not restore the iPhone "xxx" because an error occurred while reading from or writing to the iPhone"), and then "iTunes could not connect to this iPhone. An unknown error occurred (0xE800000A)."  I'll keep trying and report back.

Comment: Make sure the lightning port is clean; test another cable & another USB port. If it still fails, I'm starting to suspect the phone's RAM.

Comment: I tried 2 different cables, both Apple, and one brand new. Cleaned ports, and switched between USB ports on PC. I still have about 15Gb memory used for audio when plugging the phone into iTunes after DFU reset, and iTunes still tries to sync straight away, without me prompting it to (auto sync disabled in Preferences). Now I have an added issue with the PC, which might be another reason for the backup restore process to stall: for no obvious reason, I now get a "low memory" message, and the C drive goes down to a few Kb from a little over 1Gb, without anything else than iTunes being on..

Comment: In DFU mode, the device should not be responsive to anything other than a full reset via iTunes. It should most certainly not make any attempt to sync. The display should be the iTunes logo & an indication that it needs to be connected, nothing else. An entirely separate issue. Your PC drive is already ***critically*** over-full if you only have 1GB left. You must leave 10-15% free space even on a larger drive, more on a small one, 128GB.

Comment: Agreed. The HDD is a 500GB unit, and there is hardly anything on it apart from iTunes, because it is used solely for iTunes (the PC I use for everything else, including storing large files, runs Ubuntu). There should be a few hundred GB left on it, assuming the backup of the 256GB memory phone takes the lion's share of available space. I mentioned the 1GB free disk space only because it was what I witnessed it going down to a few dozen KB from. Next task is to fix the storage loss issue on the PC, and try to restore the backup again.